# How to upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04 without changing kernel?

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I am currently on Ubuntu 21.10, with kernel `5.13.0-22-generic`. Ubuntu 22.04 has a `5.15` kernel. I am affected by a known and **confirmed** [kernel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1963555) [bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394480/keyboard-mouse-stop-working-with-kernel-ubuntu-5-13-0-22-22-387-g0fc979747dec) that only occurs in kernel `5.15`. The patch that [introduced the bug](https://lore.kernel.org/all/20211008092547.3996295-5-mathias.nyman@linux.intel.com/) in the upstream kernel was [rebased](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-impish.git/commit/?id=0fc979747dec) into the Ubuntu kernel in version `5.13.0-23`. The patch that [fixes the bug](https://lore.kernel.org/all/Yayq%2FXdb%2FpHSS7%2Fl@kroah.com/) exists in upstream kernel `5.16`, but has not yet been rebased into the Ubuntu kernel.

For me it is paramount that I stay on kernel `5.13.0-22`, until either of 2 things happens:

1. Ubuntu uses kernel `5.16`.
2. Ubuntu rebases upstream commit [`944207047ca4dabe8e288f653e7ec6da05e70230`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=944207047ca4dabe8e288f653e7ec6da05e70230) into the Ubuntu kernel.

How do I run the upgrade from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04 while making absolutely sure that the active, current default kernel `5.13.0-22-generic` is not changed? This kernel bug affects USB devices (keyboard, mouse), so I will be completely locked out of my computer if I have the wrong kernel.

Comment: Silly question, but why upgrade at all if there is a confirmed bug with such severe consequences? Give the kernel team a bit of time to resolve the issue. You still have 3 months of support with 21.10 

Comment: As it is now, I do not expect this particular kernel bug to be fixed by the kernel team in 22.04 LTS within the next 3 months, because that would imply changing the kernel to 5.16. I hope to be proven wrong but I don't have high hopes.